Create restructure android project to work with KMM Compose?
I am trying to migrate my app created using Kotlin and Jetpack compose to KMM. I want to structure it how the wizard tool for creating Compose Multiplatform project structures it. This seems harder than it should be.
How can I make the following project structure:

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.composeMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.composeCompiler)
}

kotlin {
    androidTarget {
        @OptIn(ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi::class)
        compilerOptions {
            jvmTarget.set(JvmTarget.JVM_11)
        }
    }
    
    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach { iosTarget ->
        iosTarget.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "ComposeApp"
            isStatic = true
        }
    }
    
    jvm("desktop")
    
    sourceSets {
        val desktopMain by getting
        
        androidMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.preview)
            implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
        }
        commonMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.runtime)
            implementation(compose.foundation)
            implementation(compose.material)
            implementation(compose.ui)
            implementation(compose.components.resources)
            implementation(compose.components.uiToolingPreview)
            implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel)
            implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.compose)
        }
        desktopMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
            implementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.swing)
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "org.reference.project"
    compileSdk = libs.versions.android.compileSdk.get().toInt()

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "org.reference.project"
        minSdk = libs.versions.android.minSdk.get().toInt()
        targetSdk = libs.versions.android.targetSdk.get().toInt()
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
}

dependencies {
    debugImplementation(compose.uiTooling)
}

compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "org.reference.project.MainKt"

        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
            packageName = "org.reference.project"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
        }
    }
}


This is the structure I currently have:

plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("kotlin-android")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
    id("com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin") version "2.0.1" apply false
    id("kotlin-parcelize")
    id("androidx.baselineprofile")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.compose") version "2.1.0"
}

android {
    compileSdk = 35

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "org.ballistic.dreamjournalai"
        minSdk = 27
        targetSdk = 35
        versionCode = 71
        versionName = "1.2.8"
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            isShrinkResources = true
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("debug")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
        buildConfig = true
    }

    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }

    namespace = "org.ballistic.dreamjournalai"

    kapt {
        correctErrorTypes = true
    }
}

composeCompiler {
    enableStrongSkippingMode = true

    reportsDestination = layout.buildDirectory.dir("compose_compiler")
}

Note: Using the template for the Kotlin Multiplatform Shared Module does not achieve what I want
After adding a directory it does not look like the first screenshot
Adding folder

Most of this is defined in your app level's build.gradle file. Please [edit] your question and copy it there. Please also verify that your file structure is actually like your first screenshot shows, i.e. you have an androidMain, commonMain, desktopMain and iosMain subfolder in your src folder, with androidMain being your previous main.

@tyg I added the changes you requested to the original post. The first screenshot and gradle is from a project I created using https://kmp.jetbrains.com/
The second screenshot is what I currently have and I want to structure my project so it looks identical or close to the default on from wizard.
